# Should I have my global variables in the Application class or an Activity that all activities extend

Tags: android

Right now all my tools that I need (a DatabaseHelper singleton, an ImageLoader singleton, a PhotoHandler, a custom Toast Maker) are initialized in the onCreate of an Activity that all my activities extend from, but I just now realized that every time a new activity is started, these all get instatiated anew.

So is this a problem?

Should I change to creating a Class that extends Application and have these variables there?
If so, which method of that Application class should I instantiate those?

To make the picture complete I also have a public static finals class that holds all kinds of constants like error messages and app preferences

And I have a InitialDataLoader class that is executed right after the user logs in that gets everything the user needs from the server and stores it locally.

So which should be the more suitable place for me to instantiate the forementioned tools?

Here is a part of the Activity that all my activities extend from:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    dbTools = DBTools.getInstance(this);

    // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this configuration
    // https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
    ImageLoaderConfiguration imageLoaderConfiguration = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(imageLoaderConfiguration);

    // Set global bitmap preferences
    bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inDither = false;
    bitmapOptions.inPurgeable = true;
    bitmapOptions.inInputShareable = true;
    bitmapOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    // Get an instance of the current user
    instanceOfTheCurrentUser = Transporter.instance().instanceOfTheCurrentUser;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with lazily initialized singletons with `getInstance(Context context)` method (remember to use only context.getApplicationContext() inside this methods, or else you will leak the Activity/Service instance). The lifetime of the objects will be the same as your Application object, but you won't have to do bunch of casts of `Context` to your application class:

```
public class ImageLoader {
  private ImageLoader(Context context) {
  }

  private static final ImageLoader sInstance;
  public synchronized static ImageLoader getInstance(Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
      sInstance = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I dont understand what do you mean

Comment: the ImageLoader class is taken from the Universal Image Loader library and I cannot change it. Im looking for a more big-picture solution, asking whether I should extend the Application class and put all kinds of utilities there or extend an Activity

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be good if you have them as static classes..

And you may make an initialization method for each class (as the replacement of a constructor; if you need it);
and when the class is already initialized before, make a certain flag (a boolean, for example).. so that even though you called the initialization functions many times (let's say every time an activity is started), it will be fine..

hope it helps..